# C Multiple processes: Program crashes while creating child process

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to create a child process with the following command:

```
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;    
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );


  CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        NULL,           // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi );
```

It crashes over here and I am not sure why.

1. Now my original process takes command line parameters, so do I have to pass them here also? If so then since I am not creating child process from int main() so can I do the following:

   LPTSTR szCmdline = TEXT("nmctest -s TS -r DMR -tlLDMR");

Then pass szCmdline inside CreateProcess()?

Can someone please help me why this is crashing?

Comment: yes i tried passing szCmdline but it still crashes and not dure why?

Comment: You might also like to show us how you declared and initialised `si` and `pi`.

Comment: FWIW `STARTUPINFO si = {0};` is the idiomatic way to zero initialise a struct. No need for `ZeroMemory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing because you are passing `NULL` for both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine`. You must pass a value for at least one of them. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) makes that clear.

It looks like you have also attempted to pass a value to `lpCommandLine`. But you have passed a non-modifiable string literal. Again the documentation makes it clear that is not allowed. Pass a pointer to memory that can be modified.

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

You can meet that requirement like this:

```
TCHAR szCmdline[] = _T("nmctest -s TS -r DMR -tlLDMR");
```

Personally, I see no need for `TCHAR` in this day and age. Surely you aren't still writing programs for Windows 98? I would do it like so:

```
wchar_t szCmdline[] = L"nmctest -s TS -r DMR -tlLDMR";
```

The other possible failure vector in your code is the `STARTUPINFO` parameter. Make sure that you have initialised that correctly. The most simply way to do that is like so:

```
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
```

But you might like to add a call to `GetStartupInfo`.

```
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
GetStartupInfo(&si);
```

Comment: i tried passing szCmdline for second arg but it still crashes

Comment: @Sunny I can't debug that problem because I cannot see that version of your code. However, be aware that if you are calling `CreateProcessW`, then `lpCommandLine` must refer to modifiable memory. You cannot pass a literal. Again, the documentation makes it clear.

Comment: Could you pls tell me how to do that for szCmdline?

Comment: thanks let me quickly try that out..thanks for the explanation also.

Comment: i get the following error and warning:
warning C4013: '_T' undefined; assuming extern returning int
error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Comment: @Sunny It's from `tchar.h`. You can use `TEXT` instead. Or even we could forget all about `TCHAR` and do it like so: `wchar_t szCmdline[] = L"nmctest -s TS -r DMR -tlLDMR";` which would be my recommendation.

Comment: thank you very much, it has worked now. Lets hope there are no other hidden issues.
Quick question, you said t hat lpCommandLine should be modifiable. how is LPTSTR szCmdline = TEXT("nmctest -s TS -r DMR -tlLDMR"); not modifiable..Sorry I am kinda new to this. thanks?

Comment: Because string literals are non-modifiable. The version in my answer declares an array. Which is modifiable.